# I want count of records group by time slot postgres

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have records in the table with created at DateTime column. then I want result look like

```
time window |  count
9am-3pm     |  9
3pm-6pm     |  12
```

where time window is time and count is a number if records created between this time.

Comment: What had you tried?

Comment: basically I am not getting that whether it is possible or not, I am new here to Postgres

Comment: [Date_Part](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date_part/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` with `date_part` function `GROUP BY`

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN date_part('hour',dt) BETWEEN 3 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm'
            WHEN date_part('hour',dt) BETWEEN 15 AND 18 THEN '3pm-6pm' END "time window",
      COUNT(*)
FROM T
GROUP BY  CASE WHEN date_part('hour',dt) BETWEEN 3 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm'
            WHEN date_part('hour',dt) BETWEEN 15 AND 18 THEN '3pm-6pm' END
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6ced4/5/0)**:

```
| time window | count |
|-------------|-------|
|     3pm-6pm |     1 |
|     9am-3pm |     1 |
```

Comment: do we further divide it into date so that result set look like
<pre>
Date              | time window | count |
|-----------------|------------------|---------|
|12-01-2020   |     3pm-6pm |       1 |
|12-012020    |     9am-3pm |       1 |
|13-01-2020   |     3pm-6pm |       4 |
|13-012020    |     9am-3pm |       2 |
<pre>

Comment: the above query results in my panel

SELECT CASE WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 3 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm' WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 15 AND 18 THEN '3pm-6pm' END as timewindow,COUNT(*) FROM "tickets" GROUP BY CASE WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 3 AND 15 THEN '9am-3pm' WHEN date_part('hour',created_at) BETWEEN 15 AND 18 THEN '3pm-6pm' END;
`
 timewindow | count 
-----------------+-------
 |                   |     6 |
 |9am-3pm    |    69|
(2 rows)
`

Comment: i.e. first column of a time window is blank and second contain value 9am-3pm